# Group data and retrieve every line of the grouping with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I was thinking that maybe, once the grouped data are retrieved in the C# part, I would be able loop through the list of items that were grouped.

```
var res = db.Commandes.Where(t => t.idMatiere == mod.idMatiereChoisie).GroupBy(t => t.UA_idCa);

foreach(var group in res)
{
    foreach(var groupedLines in group)
    {
        // Always a single line, this loop is useless
    }
}
```

It seems the logic applied here is more like SQL than C#: the grouping result in a single line and you won't see all the grouped items.

It's not a problem that I can't overcome

**Tactic I will use**: instead of grouping, I'll just query all the lines, and then, while looping, I will verify if `UA_idCa` is different form the previous data and that will means the next "group" has been reached.

But I wonder... How does someone normally do this cleanly, if it's possible?

Do you have to query again to retrieve a group's content?

Or is the "**Tactic I will use**" closer to what's best?

Comment: `Data` is one of those couple of words in the English language that really doesn't have a separate plural form - it's already inherently plural.  `Datas` is not a word in English - even if you talk about multiple items of information, it's still called just **data** - not "datas" - ever

Comment: Ho, I should have known by now, sorry

Comment: if you get single 'line' per group, then you don't have other values to come into this group. your code is correct, loop is not 'useless'

Comment: Yes it is, there is supposed to be 14 lines in the seconde loop, but it's always just one, the first line of the group, not the rest. Like the group is not containing ALL the line, just the first

Comment: @pwrigshihanomoronimo you were technically right... I just found the problem....

Comment: happens to all of us ;)

Comment: DB first code is sometimes annoying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is a matter of the combination of SQL server **AND** Entity Framework.

Seems like one of the value in the grouped part (a value that is different for all the line inside the group) must be marked as not null.

Because when looking for what could be a key, entity doesn't give a damn about nullable values : they could be unique, they could be never null, EF won't even check that.

Once it is marked as NOT NULL in the sql part, EF suddenly understand that there could multiple different unique values in the grouped part...

So basically This :

```
ALTER view [dbo].[Commandes] as
SELECT top(50000000)

        isnull(ex.unitAdm, '000') UnitAdm
        ,c.id as idCahier
        ,isnull(ex.unitAdm, '000') + cast(c.id as nvarchar(6)) as UA_idCa
        ,c.NomCahier
        ,[Qte]
        ,c.prix as PrixCahier

        ,sc.id, 0 as idSousCahier /* THIS IS WHAT I COULD NOT COMPLETELY RETRIEVE
        because it could be null ? */

        ,sc.NomCahier as sousCahier
        ,sc.prix as PrixSC
        ,m.id as idMatiere
        ,m.Code
        ,m.NomMatiere
        ,ep.id as idEpreuve
        ,ep.Titre

    FROM [CahierExamen] cex 
    join Cahier c on c.id = cex.Fk_Cahier
    join Examen ex on cex.FK_Examen = ex.id
    join epreuve ep on ex.FK_Epreuve = ep.id
    join Matiere m on ep.FK_Matiere = m.id
    left join SousCahier sc on c.id = sc.FK_Cahier
    order by  code, unitAdm, idCahier
GO
```

As been changed to this:

```
ALTER view [dbo].[Commandes] as
SELECT top(50000000)

        isnull(ex.unitAdm, '000') UnitAdm
        ,c.id as idCahier
        ,isnull(ex.unitAdm, '000') + cast(c.id as nvarchar(6)) as UA_idCa
        ,c.NomCahier
        ,[Qte]
        ,c.prix as PrixCahier

        ,isnull(sc.id, 0) as idSousCahier /* WOW, NOW EF UNDERSTAND
         THERE COULD BE MULTIPLE DIFFERENTS VALUES ONCE DATA ARE GROUPED*/

        ,sc.NomCahier as sousCahier
        ,sc.prix as PrixSC
        ,m.id as idMatiere
        ,m.Code
        ,m.NomMatiere
        ,ep.id as idEpreuve
        ,ep.Titre

    FROM [CahierExamen] cex 
    join Cahier c on c.id = cex.Fk_Cahier
    join Examen ex on cex.FK_Examen = ex.id
    join epreuve ep on ex.FK_Epreuve = ep.id
    join Matiere m on ep.FK_Matiere = m.id
    left join SousCahier sc on c.id = sc.FK_Cahier
    order by  code, unitAdm, idCahier
GO
```